# In an object graph fetch N level objects using eager loading and then lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose we have an object graph as below:

```
Class A {
  B b;
}
Class B {
  C c;
}
Class C {
  D d;
}
Class D {}
```

Now when I fetch the object A I want to fetch B and C using eager loading and D using lazy loading.
How this can be done in JPA or Hibernate?

Comment: The question just popped in my mind and i am not able to find any solution.

Comment: Instead of posting comments like this please [edit] your question.

Comment: just use eager in A for object B and eager in B for Object C and lazzy in C for object D

Comment: Simplest approach: define the properties `b` and `c` to use eager fetching and `d` to use lazy fetching.

Comment: @Thomas I just added comment as i don't want to clutter the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a connection between them, you can easily use FetchType.EAGER in `B` and `C` and FetchType.LAZY in `D`.

This sort of can be achieved via `@NamedEntityGraph` also.

Answer (score 1):

Just use eager in A for Object B and eager in B for Object C and lazy in C for object D

```
class A {
  //eager
  B b;
}
class B {
  //eager
  C c;
}
class C {
  //lazy
  D d;
}
class D {}
```